# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. And I'm new here

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var this_year = DateTime.now().year.toString();

class AppConfig {
  static String copyright_text = "@ SaavaTech" + this_year; //this shows in the splash 
  screen
  static String app_name = "SaavaTech"; //this shows in the splash screen

  //configure this
  static const bool HTTPS = false;

  //configure this
  // static const DOMAIN_PATH = "192.168.0.106/ecommerce_demo";
  static const DOMAIN_PATH = "shop.muwongehassan.com";
  //static const DOMAIN_PATH = "adbuild.ae";

  //do not configure these below
  static const String API_ENDPATH = "api/v2";
  static const String PUBLIC_FOLDER = "public";
  static const String PROTOCOL = HTTPS ? "https://" : "http://";
  static const String RAW_BASE_URL = "${PROTOCOL}${DOMAIN_PATH}";
  static const String BASE_URL = "${RAW_BASE_URL}/${API_ENDPATH}";

  //configure this if you are using amazon s3 like services
  //give direct link to file like https://[[bucketname]].s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
  //otherwise do not change anythink
  static const String BASE_PATH = "${RAW_BASE_URL}/${PUBLIC_FOLDER}/";
}
```

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request with the flutter plugin HTTP but I am getting an error of the title. Does anyone know the cause of this since in my other applications this works just perfectly fine?

```
final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/signup",
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: post_body);
```

I'm trying the access the url links from the app_config.dart file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http). Since version 0.13, there has been [a breaking change](https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog). The API changed and now accepts a `Uri` object instead of a `String` for the url parameter.
There are still a lot of outdated tutorials and posts that are using a `String` instead of a `Uri`.

You can create a `Uri` as follows:

```
final url = Uri.parse("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/signup");
```

Afterwards, use it in the `post` method:

```
final response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: post_body,
);
```

Comment: yes i'm using http_package

Comment: thank you, it too worked for me in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/signup"), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: post_body);
```

Comment: thanks so much, the mere fact that i have alot of links to configure these solution can work as a short cut

Comment: You're most welcome, please consider marking it as the answer to your question, thanks!